# BrainTree - Authorize credit card for a certain amount

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, braintree

Using BrainTree API, is it possible to check if a credit card can be charged a certain amount before actually performing transaction? Lets say I have stored a customer's credit card token and before providing him with my service I want to make sure that that card can be charged a certain amount. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There are a couple of different ways to have confidence that you'll be able to charge a card when you're ready. They're outlined in the [Braintree Article on Managing Authorizations](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/managing-authorizations).

Basically, you can either perform a [card verification](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server/payment-method-management/verifications) or one or more [transactions that you void and don't submit for settlement](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server/transaction-processing/create). The second method is what you describe in the question; you verify you *could* charge a card an amount, but don't actually charge it (though you hold the funds temporarily until you void the charge or the charge expires).